# Angular 5 HttpClient : how to set interceptor to only filtered URLs by RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

Under my **angular 5 app** ,
I'm writing an **interceptor** service :

```
@Injectable()
export class myInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const tokenInHeader = req.clone({setHeaders: {'version': '1LF'}});
    return next.handle(tokenInHeader);
  }
}
```

This is results on attaching the header *"version*" to all my http requests , which is not what i want

My purpose is how may i **filter** my https request by url with **RegExp** , and attach the *"version"* header to only the matching urls

**Something like this :**

```
request(new RegExp('^api/monitoring|^api/guiTrackers|^/api/monitoring|^/api/guiTrackers'))
```

**Suggestions??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use an if condition and pass through the original request when false:

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (new RegExp('^api/monitoring|^api/guiTrackers|^/api/monitoring|^/api/guiTrackers').test(req.url)) {
      const tokenInHeader = req.clone({ setHeaders: { 'version': '1LF' } });
      return next.handle(tokenInHeader);
    } else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
```